# httparty NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I use Ruby 2.5.0, httparty gem
My model

```
class FeedEntry
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :guid, type: String
  field :url, type: String
  field :share_count, type: Integer, default: 2

  before_update :share_info

  def share_info
    checked_url = self.url
    json_stats = HTTParty.get("http://api.sharedcount.com/?url=#{checked_url}&apikey=#{Rails.application.credentials.socialshared_api_key}", timeout: 180, open_timeout: 1200)
    self.share_count = json_stats['Facebook']['share_count']
  end
end
```

And when I try to parse i have this error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

/Users/ipatov/rails_projects/apps/tm/app/models/feed_entry.rb:71:in `share_info'
```

**71 line** self.share_count = json_stats['Facebook']['share_count']

Comment: Apparently, `json_stats['Facebook']` is nil. And you can't call `['share_count']` on nil. Thus the error.

Comment: @jvillian how to avoid this?

Comment: Perhaps you should add the content of `json_stats` to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of most common errors regarding what [Rollbar says](https://rollbar.com/blog/top-10-ruby-on-rails-errors/#2-nomethoderror-undefined-method--for-nilnilclass)

The problem must be than `json_stats['Facebook']` is `nil`, so accessing to `['share_count']` produces an error. I recommend you to use [dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) to prevent this undesired error and decide what to do when `json_stats['Facebook']` is `nil`.

```
    self.share_count = json_stats.dig('Facebook', 'share_count')
```

Comment: Good thought. Perhaps, for the sake of clarity, you might add the usage of `dig` to your answer.

Comment: done, please find it edited. I also added a link to the dig hash method